# How can I find the log group by using log stream name?

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I failed to deploy a cloudformation stack and by looking at cloudformation console, it gave me an error message like below image. It says `See the details in CloudWatch Log Stream:` but it doesn't tell me what the log group is. How do I find the log stream without knowing log group name?

[image]